# Is this the correct preposition? "... arranged vaccination appointments between employees and occupational health nurses."

Tags: prepositions

"... arranged vaccination appointments between employees and occupational health nurses."

Q: Is "between" the correct preposition? Or, should "with" be used instead?

Comment: Context: Jane is an office administrator who coordinates the appointments between employees and nurses. Jane does not actually attend the appointments.

Comment: "Between" is fine, and better than "with".  For clarity one might restructure the sentence to indicate that Jane arranged appointments with the nurses, on behalf of the employees.  But the original has little chance of being misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you changed it to "... arranged employees' vaccination appointments with occupational health nurses." If it were a meeting, then "between" would fit perfectly.

Comment: exactly. Nurses don't have appointments with patients; patients have appointment with nurses. It's asymmetrical.  Using "between" is too symmetrical. +1

Comment: If it were a meeting, then "between" would fit perfectly.

Comment: Please edit your rational into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Neither sounds odd to me, but I think "between" is better in this case because it implies that Jane is not actually part of the appointments herself; she's just a [middleman](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/middleman).

Answer (score 0):

I think if you said "scheduled" instead of "arranged" would be better. If this is for a resume, I would recommend a shorter description, i.e.: "scheduled employee vaccinations."  Noting that vaccinations are normally given by some sort of health care provider I don't see specifically naming "Occupational Health Nurse" being needed.